# GORM - fetch results in List of Map form using HQL

Tags: grails, arraylist, hashmap, hql, grails-orm

I have a domain name `TestCase`. I'm fetching the data using `HQL` as below :-

```
def query = """
          select 
          tc.testCaseObjective as tco,
          tc.testCaseStatus as tcs
          from TestCase tc

        """

println TestCase.executeQuery(query, [max: 2])
```

It gives me output as :-

```
[["Test Case 01", "Pass"], ["work order", "Pass"]]
```

which is in `List` of `List` form.

But actually I want `List` of `Map` form as :-

```
[[tco:"Test Case 01", tcs:"Pass"], [tco:"work order", tcs:"Pass"]]
```

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this? I don't want to convert it explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the solution using the `select new map` syntax in `HQL` to fetch the results in `List` of `Map` as below :-

```
def query = """
          select 
          new map(tc.testCaseObjective as tco,
          tc.testCaseSummary as tcs)
          from TestCase tc

        """

println TestCase.executeQuery(query, [max: 2])
```

Output :-

```
[[tco:"Test Case 01", tcs:"Pass"], [tco:"work order", tcs:"Pass"]]
```